# Inconsistent behavior when adding duplicate tag into Favorites/Ignored Tags List

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, tag-watching, ignored-tags

Step to reproduce

1. Add some tags (between 6-10) into Ignored/Favorites tags
2. Click the area outside the textbox then refresh the page
3. Add the same tags into Ignored/Favorites tags.
4. Repeate **step 1-3** until the system begin to act weird i.e. allow you to adding the duplicate tags :(
5. After successfully added duplicated tags, repeat **step 2**.
6. After refresh, duplicated tags was cleaned from the list :)

Here the some gif animation to describe it.

> [image: duplicate tags]

Although in the end the duplicate tags was cleaned, it would be very nice if we have the **consistent behavior** from the system.

Note:

- This inconsistent behavior also reproducible in Stack Overflow and Server Fault.
- This has been tested in Windows 7 with browser Chrome 40.0.2214.111 and Firefox 35.0.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was that only the initially hidden ignored tags were not considered when checking for duplicates, as they are wrapped in a div, and the duplicate check only looked at .children() of the parent container.

Fix will be rolling out with build rev `2015.2.11.3064` on meta and `2015.2.11.2284` on sites.